# Can people see that you've liked their retweet on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, retweet

So if somebody retweets something on Twitter and you click to view it, but click onto the original account that tweeted it and like it from there, will the person who retweeted it get a notification?

Comment: No, the retweeter wont get a notification if you like it from the authors timeline - they will only get a notification if you like it from the retweeters timeline

Comment: @hd.: Please don't answer in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, the retweeter won't get a notification if you like it from the authors timeline, they will only get a notification if you like it from the retweeters timeline (since it's an action on their activity).